Connection processing ended abnormally. System.InvalidOperationException: Handle is already used by another Socket
When running my .net core 6 mvc app in linux (debian 11) container getting below error after certain successive calls to same controller action. This action readd the http response body and perform some DB operation and then return json object in response.
the full error stack is below-
 2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00  [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   Connection processing ended abnormally.
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   System.InvalidOperationException: Handle is already used by another Socket.
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEngine.TryRegisterCore(IntPtr socketHandle, SocketAsyncContext context, Error& error)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEngine.TryRegisterSocket(IntPtr socketHandle, SocketAsyncContext context, SocketAsyncEngine& engine, Error& error)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.TryRegister(Error& error)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.OperationQueue`1.StartAsyncOperation(SocketAsyncContext context, TOperation operation, Int32 observedSequenceNumber, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.ReceiveAsync(Memory`1 buffer, SocketFlags flags, Int32& bytesReceived, Action`5 callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.DoOperationReceive(SafeSocketHandle handle, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketReceiver.WaitForDataAsync(Socket socket)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoReceive()
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.BeginRead(ValueTask`1& awaitable)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
    2024-04-12T17:13:16.217-07:00   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

I enabled debug level log to find out more on the issue. This only points out to the problem that after few attempts, the the socket connections are not closing gracefully for that endpoint call.

After enabling debug level log in container It was found out that the kestrel was not closing the socket connection gracefully after few uploads.
Why it was not closing the connection gracefully? because we were creating and disposing SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero)instances through the code.
These blog posts helped me to find the root cause and put a fix for this.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64305
https://github.com/fabian-blum/AspNetCore.Identity.LiteDB/pull/14
